# Which activity should come up first? defined as launcher?

Tags: android-activity, android-intent, launcher

If I have a login screen and then the activity which displays the main functionality of my application.

Which one should be deemed as the default=launcher activity?

Should I have the login screen as launcher which will be skipped if the username/password exist in the preferences?
Or should I have my Main activity as a launcher which should start the login activity if no user/password are present?

I have found the following google guiding lines:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/seamlessness.html

Look at the title: Don't Overload a Single Activity Screen

I am not sure that I have understood it correctly, but if I did, then it means that the login screen should be the launcher screen.

Am I correct?
What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a common sense what to do.

On successfully login save username and password in sqlite database or save in `SharedPreferences`. and check data allready exist in side `oncreate()` method og Login Activity

if **username** and **password** exist in `SharedPreferences` or sqlite database. start your activity in which you have main functionality.